# Клик по координатам c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

Нужно воспроизвести клик мышкой по заданным координатам, делаю так :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(Convert.ToInt32(X), Convert.ToInt32(Y));

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y, 0, 0);
```

Все хорошо, только, если я пытаюсь кликнуть в диспетчере задач, то клик не происходит, позиция мыши меняет, но клик не нажимает. В чем проблема ?

Comment: А как вы думаете, было бы нормально, если бы Windows разрешала сторонним приложениям кликать в диспетчере задач?

Comment: Для каких целей вы это пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: @Андрей ну да )) логично, а можно как-то обойти ?

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков я делаю чтот на подобии тимвивера

Comment: Если бы можно было просто обойти, какой смысл тогда запрещать?

Comment: @VladD никто не говорит, что это просто :) Иначе я бы сюда не писал, скорее всего. Так вы мне поможете ?

Comment: Если вы хотите подключаться и управлять удаленным ПК в плане системы, то можно посмотреть в сторону PowerShell.

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков мне нужно именно раб стол видеть. Я сделал так : от клиента посылаю скрины экрана, на сервере обрабатываю, считаю координаты клика мышки относительно изображения, посылаю клиенту, а клиент уже кликает по координатам. Тут важную роль играет скорость интернет соед, но другого я ничего не придумал

Comment: @Lolidze: Ну, если вас слово «драйвер» не пугает, можно попробовать посмотреть в эту сторону. Заодно сможете обрабатывать ситуации, когда юзер находится в экране блокировки по Ctrl-Alt-Del.

Comment: @VladD пугает )) есть еще способы ? что интересно, в таких программах, как pchunter тоже не кликается ((

Comment: была еще проблема, когда запускаешь от админа ехе и вылазит окошко "разрешить или нет", тогда скрин вообще черный посылался, решил с помощью отключение контроля учетных записей, костыль, конечно, но другого способа не нашел ((

Comment: @Lolidze: Я других способов не знаю. Ну то есть я не знаю и как написать драйвер, конечно. Но вроде бы это то, что делает TeamViewer.

Comment: Есть способ, почитайте про Coded UI, это технология от MS, для доступа к элементам интерфейса Windows.

Но советую несколько раз подумать, стоит ли заниматься этим и тратить время.

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков этж тесты, разве его можно использовать, как полноценное ехе ? Кликать нужно так : `Mouse.Click(uIDesktopList, new Point(792, 792));` , где `uIDesktopList` - элемент, на который нужно кликнуть. Есть несколько вопросов : 1. Как сделать, что бы кликал относительно всего экрана  2.Можно ли через параметры запуска или еще как-то посылать координаты клика ? ведь они динамичны